# Which is correct? "Until the 1990s, no one knew the fact." or "Until the 1990s, no one had known the fact."

Tags: grammar

I think "Until the 1990s, no one had known the fact." is grammatically true. Is the other one using the past tense is acceptabe? Or it is also true? Or it is not grammatically true?

Comment: What does **grammatically true** mean? 「文法的に正しい」は英語に"grammatical"になります。

Answer (score 2):

Both of your examples are correct. Both indicate an action that occurred (and was completed) in the past.

> Until the 1990s, no one knew the fact.

All the action remains in the simple past.

Bernard Comrie, a Distinguished Professor of Linguistics,  classifies the [pluperfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect) as an absolute-relative tense, because it absolutely (not by context) establishes a past event, and places the action relative to the past event (before it).

> A man who for years *had thought* he *had reached* the absolute limit of all possible suffering now *found* that suffering had no limits, and that he could suffer still more, and more intensely. (Frankl, Man's Search for Meaning)

Until the 1990s, no one had known the fact... (is incomplete because there remains a relative event in the past related to the action of the previous past.)

> Until the 1990s, no one had known the fact that he was an unhappily married man, but his sudden divorce in 1992 and his move to Tahiti to paint *made* that abundantly clear.

**Edited** to correct an **error**. Apologies to all.

Comment: I don't quite understand that "however". It *seems* to imply that although the pluperfect is "correct", people "often use simpler constructions". But I think both are perfectly valid *in the right context* (and OP's is potentially "right" for both). On the other hand, pluperfect is decidedly ugly in, for example, *"Until last year he had been a happily-married man."*

Comment: Actually, when I wrote that comment I was thinking of a context where my italicised example immediately followed something like *"He lives in a monastery now, **but**..."*. By which I mean that the pluperfect only works if there's another *later* "reference time" closely associated with the utterance, but that later time still has to be in the past. So whereas *"Until yesterday I had been happy in my job, but now I'm thinking of moving on"* sounds awful to me. But it would be fine if it had been *"...but **then they changed my contract,** so now I'm thinking of leaving"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You're right. That was a definite miss on my part. Thanks for getting me to see it.

Comment: I'll freely admit I didn't have a clear understanding of the different contexts wherein **until** + pluperfect or simple past would be appropriate. All I knew was without context there's no real reason to favour *"Until then I **had** enjoyed life"* over *"Until then I enjoyed life"*, or vice-versa. Well, I suppose the specific word "then" somewhat implies your "reference time" is *still* in the past for something else you might be talking about, but you see my point. Whatever - the answer is now comprehensive, but I'll leave my comments in case they help anyone else later.